# Rename a table in the database using PDO statements

Tags: php, database, pdo

I building a social networking website. There is that settings page, where the user can update his/her information. For example he/she can update username, the problem is that there are some tables that are named like ( $username . "_posts" ), so off course if the user updated the username i want be able to access these tables again. So, I want to rename these tables using the updated username to be able to access them on other pages.

I have tried:

```
$rename_table = "RENAME `" . $old_username . "_posts` TO `" . $updated_username . "_posts`";                    $prepare_stmt = $conn->prepare($rename_table);
$prepare_stmt->execute();
```

and also without the (`) like:

```
$rename_table = "RENAME " . $old_username . "_posts TO " . $updated_username . "_posts";                    $prepare_stmt = $conn->prepare($rename_table);
$prepare_stmt->execute();
```

I expect the table names to be updated, but I always get this error:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`some_username_posts` TO `some_newusername_posts`' at line 1

NOTE: I am using PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the problem is that there are some tables that are named like `( $username . "_posts" )`

Don't do that. MySQL/MariaDB does not handle schemas with very large numbers of tables well.

Use a single table to store all posts, and store the user's ID or name as a column in that table.

That being said, your problem is that the command you are trying to use is called `RENAME TABLE`, not just `RENAME`.